# Checking a CheckBox by clicking a Button element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am revising Core React.js concepts and I am having a hard time doing this.
I have the App component that displays a checkbox, a div section that displays a message and a counter value, and two buttons that change the div section message and increment the counter
The component has state data for the message, counter, and theme.

What I want to achieve is this.
First I want to prevent the checkbox default behavior by using preventDefault
Second I want to toggle the checkbox from unchecked to checked by clicking one of the button element of the component.

Here is the code I wrote

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super (props);
        this.state = {
            message: 'Ready',
            counter: 0,
            theme: 'secondary'
        }
    }

    handleEvent = (event, newTheme) => {
        event.persist();
        this.setState({ 
            counter: this.state.counter + 1,
            theme: newTheme
        },() => {
            this.setState({ message: `${event.type}: ${this.state.counter}`});
            this.toggleCheckBox()
        });
    }

    toggleCheckBox = (event) => {
        if (this.state.counter === 0) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="m-2">
                <div className="form-check">
                    <input className="form-check-input" type="checkbox"
                        onClick={ this.toggleCheckBox } />
                    <label>This is a checkbox</label>
                </div>
                <div className={ `h4 bg-${this.state.theme} 
                                    text-white text-center p-2`}>
                    { this.state.message }
                </div>
                <div className="text-center">
                    <button className="btn btn-primary"
                            onClick={ (e) => this.handleEvent(e, "primary") }>
                            Normal
                    </button>
                    <button className="btn btn-danger m-1"
                            onClick={ (e) => this.handleEvent(e, "danger") }>
                            Danger
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you create a sandbox for the same?

Comment: I am not sure to understand your question.